# linq query to update boolean field in table with where condition

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to update one field in db which is of type Boolean. This is the table structure

usr_id  int False
usr_fname   nvarchar(50)
usr_lname   nvarchar(50)
usr_username    nvarchar(50)
usr_password    nvarchar(MAX)
usr_email   nvarchar(50)
usr_pwdresetstatus  bit

This is something I am trying

```
public int ForGotPassword(string username, string emailid)
      {
          var result = db.tm_usr_usermaster.Where(m => m.usr_username == username && m.usr_email==emailid).Select(m => m.usr_isactive).SingleOrDefault();
          bool isactive = Convert.ToBoolean(result);
          if(isactive==false)
          {
            //Update query
          }
          else
          {

          }
```

I am receiving parameters username and email id if both matches pwdresetstatus should be updated as true. I can write sql equivalent here
`Update tablename set pwdresetstatus=true where usr_username==username && usr_email==emailed`. I have difficult times to go ahead

I tried this

```
tm_usr_usermaster users = db.tm_usr_usermaster.FirstOrDefault(x => x.usr_email==emailid && x.usr_username==username);
              users.usr_pwdresetstatus = true;
              db.SaveChanges();
```

and working fine. Thank you stephen

Comment: Did you mean `.Select(m => m.usr_pwdresetstatus)`? And why are you using `Convert.ToBoolean()` when the result is already `bool`?

Comment: yes pwdresetstatus  I want to update and in where condition I need to check email and username. pwdresetstatus   is a Boolean field. If isactive is false then inside the flower brackets I need update query

Comment: Then you need to update the property and save the object.

Comment: Yes I tried as updated above thank you Stephen... Post answer please

Comment: You worked it out for yourself so feel free to ad your own answer :)

Comment: I don't know about it but one small doubt. Above query I created in separate class inside the business layer. In the above code in else part I want to display error message. So how to achieve this?

Comment: Display a message where? You could make the method `public string ForGotPassword()` and return a message that way. Or if its really an 'error' you could throw an exception with the message. But why not just return `bool` indicating success or otherwise, and then in the controller, generate your message based on it and display it in the view. Difficult to know what the best or most appropriate solution is without know more about what your trying to so.